# How does the asynchronous function return the final value?

Tags: javascript

When I use the Dojo framework to create a class, the class has a method that uses an asynchronous function, and what else can I do to make it only return the final value, not a Promise or other?

Comment: you can't turn an asynchronous function synchronous - ever

Comment: Really can not solve it？

Comment: really, asynchronous functions (like asynchronous XMLHttpRequest for example) can not be turned synchronous - it's actually quite obvious why

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is probably a bad example as it can be synchronous - just that the asynchronous form can't return a result synchronously

Answer (score 0):

you must use a callback function, example:

```
function myDojoFunction(id, callback) {
   require(['dojo/dom'], function (dom) {
      if (dom.byId(id)) callback (true);
   });
}
```

to call function:

```
myDojoFunction('myId', function (exists) {
   if (exists) console.log('i'm here');
   else console.log('i'm not here');
});
```

that's the way to return something if you are working with dojo AMD instead of legacy.